# How to most efficiently split a date represented as a string in Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called `start_date` in my Pandas data frame in string format:

### `start_date`

`'20120212'`

`'20120514'`

`'20121124'`

`'20120604'`

To extract and create separate columns for month, year and day, this is what I am doing currently. Are there better methods to do the same?

`df['start_month']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[4:6])`

`df['start_year']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[0:4])`

`df['start_day']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[6:8])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then extract years, months and days:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['start_month'] = a.dt.month
df['start_year'] = a.dt.year
df['start_day'] = a.dt.day
```

Or slice by `str[]` and cast to `int`:

```
df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].astype(str)
df['start_month'] = df['start_date'].str[4:6].astype(int)
df['start_year']=df['start_date'].str[:4].astype(int)
df['start_day']=df['start_date'].str[6:8].astype(int)
print (df)
  start_date  start_month  start_year  start_day
0   20120212            2        2012         12
1   20120514            5        2012         14
2   20121124           11        2012         24
3   20120604            6        2012          4
```

Comparing solutions:

```
[40000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def orig(df):
    df['start_month']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[4:6]).astype(int)
    df['start_year']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[0:4]).astype(int)
    df['start_day']=df['start_date'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[6:8]).astype(int)
    return df

def a(df):
    a = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df['start_month'] = a.dt.month
    df['start_year'] = a.dt.year
    df['start_day'] = a.dt.day
    return df

def b(df):
    df['start_month'] = df['start_date'].str[4:6].astype(int)
    df['start_year']=df['start_date'].str[:4].astype(int)
    df['start_day']=df['start_date'].str[6:8].astype(int)
    return df
```

---

```
In [135]: %timeit (orig(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 64.8 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit (a(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 35 ms per loop

In [137]: %timeit (b(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop
```